# PandaTables and Exif - adding columns as needed

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So I'm trying to use the incredible Pandastable to display jpeg exif data from a csv file. I'm processing these files with exifread, writing it to a csv and then importing with Pandastable on a tk.button click with the following code:

```
def load_file():
fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("JPEG/TIFF files", "*.jpg;*.tiff"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*")))
f = open(fname,'r')

fdata.update(exifread.process_file(f, details=False))

with open('tempdata.csv', 'a') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fdata.keys(),extrasaction="raise")
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(fdata)

datatable.importCSV('tempdata.csv')
```

My issue is that each file has variable data fields, so img1 might have 50 fields, whereas img2 might have 51 fields. This throws up the following error:

*CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 50 fields in line 13, saw 51*

So what I'd like to do is that if img2 has extra data fields, it adds those to the table.

I've tried to create a list of all datafields first in my own dictionary, but due to the way that exifread works, this doesn't seem to work well as there are many, many different variations of tags - I'm also hoping to expand this to other file types which would make this hard to maintain.

I also don't want to just ignore these columns, as most of the other similar questions have as an answer.

Any ideas how I could add these columns on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a basic example. I'm not sure what your final output is supposed to be. Are you trying to concat the two dataframes into one?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,1,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,np.NaN,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,5], 
                    'C' : ['AA1233445','AA1233445', 'rmacy','Idaho Rx','Ab123455','TV192837','RX','Ohio Drugs','RX12345','USA Pharma'], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})
print(df)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Z' : [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0] })

# if the column in df2 is not in df, create a column in df
# I'm just setting it to 0 in the example, but you could fill it with whatever for your case

for columns in df2.columns.tolist():
    if columns not in df.columns.tolist():
        df[str(columns)] = 0
```

EDIT: or you could do `df[str(columns)]  = df2[str(columns)]` or something like that.

Comment: Hi MattR, thanks for answering. Pandastable doesn't look to work round the dataframes for some reason so I'll try to clarify.

Basically, each time I open a file, I process it with the module exifread which gives me a dict of stuff like {'image_size':'1024x768'....}
I want to write this to a csv file and then display it using the pandastable module. I then want to open another file, process it and add it to that csv.

Unfortunately, if img2 has more columns than img1, it throws up the error above. So if python detects more columns in img2, id like to add those into the CSV.

Comment: You could read the dictionaries in with [`pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), Merge/Concat (whichever is appropriate) the new dataframe and use the same logic as in my answer. Does that help at all? It's hard to come up with a concrete example without seeing what you're looking at

Comment: Thanks MattR, your suggestions pointed me exactly in the right direction - I ended up redoing it and will edited my answer with the way I managed it.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I hacked it together with the help of MattR's comments:

```
def load_file():
  global header_set, df
  fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("JPEG/TIFF files", "*.jpg;*.tiff"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*")))
  f = open(fname,'r')

  fdata.update(exifread.process_file(f, details=False))

  df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(fdata, index=[0])
  print df2
  df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
  print df
  pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df,path_or_buf='tempdata.csv', index=False)

  datatable.importCSV('tempdata.csv')
  datatable.redraw()
```

'df' was then used as the dataframe for pandastable on tkinter.

Comment: It would help others coming to this post to use the correct indentation :)